# Is 0521 and 521 are same NUMBER?

Tags: permutations, combinations

In a question related to permutations, its been asked to find the number of NUMBERS with less than 5 digits that can be made using 0,1,2,3,4,5.
Instead of NUMBERS, if it was ARRANGEMENTS I know that 0521 and 521 are two different arrangements...But if it is NUMBERS, do we need to consider 0521 and 521 as two different numbers or one number ??

Comment: IMHO they are the same number.  But really, it's not altogether clear and you should ask your instructor.

Comment: A string of digits can be a *decimal system representation* of a number (integer), but the number is not the same thing as its representation.  In fact the number can be represented in different ways (e.g. different bases other than base ten).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `0521` is *usually* not considered a "number" for these kinds of questions.   From experience one is *typically* expected to exclude *strings* with leading zeroes.

However, if still in doubt, as your lecturer for clarification.

(Or you could always give both answers, as the modification to exclude leading zeroes is not that difficult.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are the same numbers.

I think the point of the exercise was to notice this and discard all the combinations where the left-most digit is a $0$.